# Ran direct SQL update to bulk update contact names, changes not appearing until editing and saving

Tags: contacts, database, sql

I'm finishing up a migration to CiviCRM from a homegrown Python application I wrote, and without going into too much detail as to the why, I needed to do a bulk update of all the contact name fields in the civicrm_contact table using a spreadsheet dump from the old application.

I wrote a script that loops over the rows in the spreadsheet and runs an update statement on each record in civicrm_contact table using the external_identifier field to match.

This all seems to have run fine, but when I go to the contact in CiviCRM the old values are still there. However, when I click at the top of the contact screen to put the name fields into edit mode, the new values are in the form fields, and when I hit save the new values appear.

Is there some caching going on such that this will fix itself, or does updating the name fields directly as I did have some other implications/consequences I should be aware of? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you imported the `first_name` and `last_name` values - but the value at the top of the record is the `display_name`.  You have two options:

- Use your SQL script to update the `display_name` accordingly.
- Export ONLY the `contact_id` of the affected records (or all records).  Reimport the contact ID via the "Import Contacts" functionality.  All records will be resaved when you import the contact ID and the `display_name` is recalculated on save.

Incidentally, this is a good if fairly harmless example of why directly updating the database via SQL is usually a bad idea.  If this were imported via the API, the display name would have been recalculated.  In this case, there was no data loss - but if you had tried updating, e.g. donation amounts, the lack of corresponding changes to your line item and financial transaction tables would be difficult to recover from!

Comment: Thank you! This is great information to have. I'll look into the API more since i have some regular updating I need to do from an outside source. Since I'm used to dealing with databases directly I figured I'd do it this way so it's great to know the consequences of this and learn more about how all the pieces fit together. I really appreciate the information.